# Windows XP Installation issue - cannot find hard disk

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, installation

A friend of mine gave me a laptop with Windows 8 installed and nothing else.  I don't like it so I am trying to remove it by installing Windows XP.

I have a windows XP installation CD that I have used before and worked fine, but didn't work when I tried to install it on the Windows 8 machine.  It keeps telling me I don't have a drive to install to.

Then I log into Windows 8 again and install check partitions.  I found 2 and tried to make a new one but it will only let me make one of 69mb.

Next, I tied to find a way to go back to XP with BCD install and try to set the boot loader for XP but it wasnt there.  Somehow I deleted the bootloader for Windows 8 and now it asks me for a recovery tool for media.

I am  not familiar with the laptop specs, but it is a Toshiba with about 250GB storage, and above 1GHz processor.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP is unable to install because it does not have a driver for the disk and/or disk controller in the laptop.

What you need to do is look up the laptop model on the Toshiba website, and download any hard disk or hard disk controller related drivers for XP.

When you boot XP, one of the first screens will ask you to hit F6 to install third party drivers.  You will be prompted for the drivers.  If I recall, XP requires these to be on a floppy disk.

Note that Windows 8 has nothing to do with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

use driver packs to slipstream "Mass storage" drivers into the XP CD.

Driver packs tutorial, read carefully.

http://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=1449

Download software "Driverpacks Base"

http://driverpacks.net/downloads

You can install other driver packs besides the "Mass Storage", but this will bloat the size of the XP install to DVD size, The only driver packs I suggest to slipstream are

Mass Storage, Chipset, Lan, CPU

This will keep it a size to fit on a CD. If you want all the drivers slipstreamed it will require a DVD burner to make the DVD and a DVD drive on the target installation PC.

I don't change any of the default settings when using the DriverPscks software, just pick the driver packs you want to slipstream and create the ISO image.

If you use other customizing software for other reasons than drivers such as Nlite, use Nlite first then driver packs last or install problems will result. Only use DP to slip drivers, do not use Nlite for this task.

Start with clean unmodified Installation files when using DP for best results

Note, Driverpacks no longer allows you to download the driverpacks from their site using the program (you will get an error), driverpacks are now distributed via bittorrent, the torrent file for each driverpack can be found on the driverpacks download page, or sign up on this forum and you can download driver packs directly. http://reboot.pro/forum/88/
Driver packs for XP will be labeled "wnt5_x86-32"

Once you have the 7zip Driverpack files you need, copy them (do not unzip them) into the "DriverPacks" folder where you installed the "Base" program. When you run the program skip the update driverpacks step in the process. Once they are slipstreams compile the ISO, then burn to disc.